# How can I replace a head on a specific level?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, head

So in my notebook I have a list of long expressions which are sums of a bunch of terms. I would like to look at each of these terms individually and try to remove them based on some criteria. My idea was to replace the head of the first Plus with List, and then look at the individual terms from there as they would be separated into a list. I want to use Replace instead of ReplaceAll because on lower levels there may be sums inside exponentials that I don't want to replace. A toy illustration of what I'm doing now (which doesn't work) is something like this:

```
Replace[{x+y},Plus -> List, 1]
```

In my mind this should work, but it doesn't seem to. ReplaceAll works ok

```
ReplaceAll[{x+y},Plus -> List]
```

but I don't think this is really what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated, or even a different way of approaching the problem would be great too!

Comment: Even if `Replace` worked that way, the third argument should have been `{2}`. `Plus` is at level 2 because you need two numbers to obtain it with part `{x+y}[[1,0]]`

Comment: You could write `MapAt[List&, expr, Position[expr, Plus, {2}]]`

Comment: `Apply`with a level specification may be what you need : `Apply[List,{x+y},{1}]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the option `Heads -> True`. The default behavior of `Replace` is to ignore heads like `Plus`.

```
Replace[{x + y}, Plus -> foo, {2}, Heads -> True]
```

> `{foo[x, y]}`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly